# keeping the fields order of mysql json query

Tags: mysql

I have the following `MySQL` json query:

```
SELECT
  json_object('personId', p.id, 'personName', p.name, 'personAge', p.age)
FROM
  PEOPLE p;
```

and I noticed that `json_object` does not return the fields in the order enumerated on the query, is that possible to change? if I do want the same order, can I do that?

For example, the output can be:

```
{
  "personAge": 35,
  "personId": 12,
  "personName": "john"
}
```

but I want it to always be:

```
{
  "personId": 12,
  "personName": "john",
  "personAge": 35
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a sample of data, what this query output from that sample, and what you expect to get.

Comment: What do you mean by *json_object does not return the fields in the order of the query* ? You are normally getting one JSON object per row in table people, what is wrong from your perspective ?

Comment: @Shidersz added example

Comment: @GMB added example

Comment: @JohnBigs Did you happen to find a solution to manage ordering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't manage the order of the keys for the generated `JSON`. If we refer to this: [Normalization, Merging, and Autowrapping of JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-normalization), we can see that one of the steps used on the normalization of `JSON` values includes the next logic:

> To make lookups more efficient, it also sorts the keys of a JSON object. You should be aware that the result of this ordering is subject to change and not guaranteed to be consistent across releases.

And then, a paragraph later, we can read:

> MySQL functions that produce JSON values (see Section 12.17.2, “Functions That Create JSON Values”) always return normalized values.

So, in summary, `json_object()` is a function that return a `JSON` value, this value will be normalized, and part of the normalization procedure can affect the order of the `JSON keys`.